# Symfony2 createFormBuilder - Dynamic Advanced Search Form

Tags: symfony

I'm consuming an API, which as part of the response, returns an array called "form". This is an array of field names, data types and values.

The number of, and name of these fields can be different depending on what API endpoint is currently being consumed. But the structure of the form array is always the same. So the process as far as Symfony is concerned is the following:

1. Create a form object
2. Loop through the form array and add array elements as fields
3. Send the array to the view

Basically, this form is nothing more than an advanced search form. There is absolutely no link to Entities in the system.

So, being new to Symfony2, and after reading this documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/forms.html#building-the-form) I tried to do this in the controller by creating the following function:

```
/**
 * Generate a form for each field passed in an array.
 * 
 * @param array $formArray A custom array of fields do be shown in the form
 * @return formView
 */
private function generateForm($formArray)
{

    // Simple demo for testing
    $formArray = array(
        0 => array(
            'name' => 'FirstName', 'type' =>'text'
            ),
        1 => array(
            'name' => 'LastName', 'type' =>'text'
            )
        ); 

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($formArray);

    foreach($formArray as $field) {
        $form->add($field['name'], $field['type']);
    }        

    $form->getForm();


    return $form->createView();

}
```

What I get from that is

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder::createView() in .... (my controller file)
```

Oddly enough, If I make adding the fields and the getForm() call a chain as per the document example, it's fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah figured it. This line

```
$form->getForm();
```

That method returns a Form object, whereas I was treating it as a setter.

So working controller function is as follows:

```
 /**
 * Generate a form for each field passed in an array.
 * 
 * @param array $formArray A custom array of fields do be shown in the form
 * @return formView
 */
private function generateForm($formArray)
{

    $formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($formArray);

    foreach($formArray as $field) {
        $formBuilder->add($field['name'], $field['type']);
    }        

    $form = $formBuilder->getForm();

    return $form->createView();

}
```